# Nurse Scheduling Problem with Or Tools, assign more than 1 nures to servel shifts

Tags: python, or-tools

I'm modifying the code from [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling)
, and I want to be able to create a shift schedule according to the preferance of the workers , that will be assigned to  2 workers for morning and evening shift and one for the night shift.
this is the original code :

```
def create_shifts():
    num_nurses = 5
    num_days = 7
    num_shifts = 3
    all_nurses = range(num_nurses)
    all_shifts = range(num_shifts)
    all_days = range(num_days)
    shift_requests, workers_names = pre_condition_for_creating_shifts(num_nurses,num_days,num_shifts)
    # Creates the model.
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    # Creates shift variables.
    # shifts[(n, d, s)]: nurse 'n' works shift 's' on day 'd'.
    shifts = {}
    for n in all_nurses:
        for d in all_days:
            for s in all_shifts:
                shifts[(n, d,
                        s)] = model.NewBoolVar('shift_n%id%is%i' % (n, d, s))

    # Each shift is assigned to exactly one nurse in.
    for d in all_days:
        for s in all_shifts:

            model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 1)

    # Each nurse works at most one shift per day.
    for n in all_nurses:
        for d in all_days:
            model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for s in all_shifts) <= 1)

    # Try to distribute the shifts evenly, so that each nurse works
    # min_shifts_per_nurse shifts. If this is not possible, because the total
    # number of shifts is not divisible by the number of nurses, some nurses will
    # be assigned one more shift.
    min_shifts_per_nurse = (num_shifts * num_days) // num_nurses
    if num_shifts * num_days % num_nurses == 0:
        max_shifts_per_nurse = min_shifts_per_nurse
    else:
        max_shifts_per_nurse = min_shifts_per_nurse + 1
    for n in all_nurses:
        num_shifts_worked = 0
        for d in all_days:
            for s in all_shifts:
                num_shifts_worked += shifts[(n, d, s)]
        model.Add(min_shifts_per_nurse <= num_shifts_worked)
        model.Add(num_shifts_worked <= max_shifts_per_nurse)

    final_shifts = []
    id = []
    # pylint: disable=g-complex-comprehension
    model.Maximize(sum(shift_requests[n][d][s] * shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses for d in all_days for s in all_shifts))
    # Creates the solver and solve.
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solver.Solve(model)
    for s in all_shifts:
        for d in all_days:
            print('Day', d)
            for n in all_nurses:
                if solver.Value(shifts[(n, d, s)]) == 1:
                    if shift_requests[n][d][s] == 1:
                        final_shifts.append(workers_names[n])
                        print('Worker', n, 'works shift', s, '(requested).')
                    else:
                        final_shifts.append("No submitted")
                        print('Worker', n, 'works shift', s, '(not requested).')
        print()
    post_condition_for_creating_shifts(final_shifts)

    # Statistics.
    print()
    print('Statistics')
    print('  - Number of shift requests met = %i' % solver.ObjectiveValue(),
          '(out of', num_nurses * min_shifts_per_nurse, ')')
    print('  - wall time       : %f s' % solver.WallTime())
```

Instead of :

```
    # Each shift is assigned to exactly one nurse in.
    for d in all_days:
        for s in all_shifts:

            model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 1)``
```

I've changed this:

```
 for d in all_days:
        for s in all_shifts:
            if s==0 or s==1:
                model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 2)
            else:
                model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 1)
    # Each nurse works at most one shift per day.
    for n in all_nurses:
        week=[]
        for d in all_days:
            for s in all_shifts:
                week.append(shifts[(n, d, s)])
                # week.append(sum(shifts[(n,d,s)] for s in all_shifts))
            model.Add(sum(week) >= 1)
            model.Add(sum(week) <= 5)
```

but I'm getting an error in the line

```
   if solver.Value(shifts[(n, d, s)]) == 1:
```

that saying: IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current example is very limited as it uses the assumption that the number of shifts is equal to the number of nurses. For a more complete example, I recommend looking at this one:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py